# stackoverflow's implementation of openid for PHP

Tags: php, authentication, oauth, openid, google-authentication

How do I implement the same login system as stackoverflow?

Where anyone can login based on their existing username/passwords from other web applications like, google, paypal, facebook, twitter and much much more?

Comment: What part of the implementation are you having problems with? Your question is too broad to answer as it stands.

Comment: I think the starting, i.e. how do I start to get a page like the stackoverflow login page with all those icons to allow someone to login with any of their existing accounts.  A tutorial would be ideal if available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For .NET you may checkout [DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/), that's what SO uses to implement OpenId authentication. So add the NuGet and [get started](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/899303.aspx). And for the nice icons checkout [openid-selector](http://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/).

For PHP you may checkout [this project](http://www.janrain.com/openid-enabled).

Answer (score 3):

There are many OpenId solutions. Here is a list.

http://openid.net/add-openid/add-getting-started/

http://openid.net/developers/libraries/

For nice looking UI as Darin Dimitrov said you need to go with

http://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/